# How can I create a system similar to QDockWidget but for tabs?

Tags: qt, qtabwidget, qdockwidget, qtabbar

I had an idea I have no clue on how to implement. I'm working with Qt and I'ld like to have a system of tabs that allows me to use tabs in the same way one can use QDockWidgets, that is: with QDockWidgets one can pick a widget and use it floating around the monitor or he can dock it in a QMainWindow in any of the four sides. Well I would like to have such attribute with a QTabWidget! So suppose I have two QTabWidgets in front of me. With the proposed idea, I would be capable to drag and drop a tab (with its widget) from one QTabWidget to another or even simply undock it from its original QTabWidget and start using it independently as another QTabWidget with one tab.

Well I couldn't find a way to use QTabWidget this way "naturally"; it seems Qt doesn't provide such possibility with its pack of widget classes. So does anybody knows any project open to the public containing a class able to do such thing? Or how could I implement such a new class myself? (I don't know for example how could I make the drag and drop effect from a QTabBar since even if `setMovable` is set to `true`, still isn't possible to make the tab go away from area of the QTabBar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

QDockWidgets already provide possibility to be tabbed.
You can check [`Dock Widgets`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html) Qt sample project in `Main Windows` section.
Screen of the just launched sample app:
[image]

Screen of the tabbed doc widgets:
[image]

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470938/2266412) for implementation details.

Comment: first, thanks for the answer, but actually QDockWidgets don't do what I want as I sad: the mechanism of forming a QTabBar when dragging and dropping only works with QDockWidgets relative to a QMainWindow's "dockable area", not between the QDockWidgets themselves (i.e. if I drag and drop one floating QDockWidget into another, they don't merge in a QTabWidget thing as they do when I drag an drop it over another QDockWidget already docked in a QMainWindow). So although it does half the work, it still isn't what I want.